# SwiftUI Animation breaks when moved to Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I want to implement a text animation in SwiftUI and made a view that boils down to something like this:

```swift
public struct AnimatedTextView: View, Animatable {

    public var number: CGFloat

    public init(number: CGFloat) {
        self.number = number
    }

    public var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { number }
        set { number = newValue }
    }

    public var body: some View {
        Text("\(Int(number))")
    }
}
```

This animation works fine in the main app target, but when I move it to a SPM package, the animation breaks:

[image: A side-by-side comparison of the same animation shown differently]

Has anybody encountered this and knows a workaround?

<sub>(Full project to reproduce the issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1yrzszxlgkk0p0/AnimationRepro.zip)</sub>

Comment: DropBox asks to create account - I don't want to, put archive somewhere available globally or just by link.

Comment: @Asperi, I was confronted with the same DropBox message, to get around, just dismiss the popup windows, then you can just download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the issue is not related to being the code inside the package, but actually to the iOS version.

I have dropped your app's *iOS Deployment Target* to **iOS 14**, and the animation appears to be broken in the *App module* as well. Then, I bumped it again to **iOS 15**, and also updated the package's `Package.swift` to have a minimum of **iOS 15** and animation did work great on both. (Make sure to clean build the project after updating the minimum version)

So it seems that the *increment/decrement* animation is something new in **iOS 15**. You might need to bump up the minimum version for the whole app (package included), or implement a custom animation with the same behaviour if lower versions are required.

Comment: Oh boy.........